# Probability Question: Find $a$ and $b$ given expected value and density function

Tags: probability, statistics

The density function of $X$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f(x) =\begin{cases}
a+bx^2, & \text{if}\,\,0\leq x\leq 1\\
0,      & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Once $\textbf{E}(X) = 4.25$, find $a$ and $b$

Comment: I attempted this question by setting up the integral of x(a+bx^2) from 0 to 1 and solving for a and b. I got a=0 and b=17. This was incorrect

Comment: The expected value is supposed to range between $0$ and $1$ ...

Comment: Please share your work/thoughts in the main post, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using legitimacy,

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = 1$$

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} (a + b x^{2}) dx = 1$$

$$ \bigg[ax + \frac{bx^{3}}{3}\bigg]_{0}^{1} = 1$$

$$ a + \frac{b}{3} = 1$$

$$ 3a + b = 3$$

Using expectation,

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} x f(x) dx = 4.25$$

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} (ax + b x^{3}) dx = 4.25$$

$$ \bigg[\frac{ax^{2}}{2} + \frac{bx^{4}}{4}\bigg]_{0}^{1} = 4.25$$

$$ \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{4} = 4.25$$

$$ 2a + b = 4 \times 4.25$$

$$ 2a + b = 17 $$

Can you take it from here?

EDIT: Turns out that after solving the equations for $a$ and $b$, $f$ takes negative values on $[0, 1]$, which makes it a wrong density function. Pointed out by @Michael Hoppe

Comment: I think there is missing a one half factor in the last expression. It should be:
$$\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{4} = 4.25$$

Comment: In that case we'll get $f(x)=-14+45x^2$.  But then $f$ would take negative values on $[0,1]$, which disqualifies it as a density function.

Answer (score 2):

To be a density function, not only the integral of $f$ over $[0,1]$ must equal $1$ -- that is, as pointed out above the case if $a=1-b/3$ -- but also $f$ must not negative in $[0,1]$.

Now a usual computation gives that $f(x)=bx^2+1-b/3$ is non-negative iff $b$ lies between $-3/2$ and $3$.

As the expected value of $X$ is $a/2+b/4=b/12+1/2$ its maximal value is obtained at $b=3$ which gives a maximum expected value of $3/4$.  Hence $E(x)=4.25$ is impossible.